# Need to create a custom object by looping the list in c# is it possible

Tags: c#

I need to create a list object based on a list of key-value pair dynamically but I can't assign the key value in object by looping the list.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> item in List)
            {
                string keyValue = item.Key.ToString();
                object value = new { item.Key = item.Value };
                somefunction(value);
            }
```

the item.key will throw issue. Any suggestions for how to create an object while looping through the list.

For example if the item value is { key: "sampleKey" , value : "sampleValue"} i need to create an object as  { "sampleKey" = "sampleValue" }. How can I achive this.

Comment: What is this supposed to do `new { item.Key = item.Value }` ? Do you mean `new { Key = item.Value }`?

Comment: Typo? Your loop returns `items`, but in the body of the loop you use `item.Key`.

Comment: From your description it sounds as if you want to create an instance of a custom object _type_ based on the attributes of `item`, but if you could successfully do that, what would the signature of `someFunction` look like in order to accept such objects?

Comment: Maybe you should explain what the underlying requirement is?

Comment: Do you mean a `,` instead of  `=` in the line `object value = new { item.Key = item.Value }; `?

Comment: Please provide sample code that will compile without error. 
object value = new { item.Key = item.Value }; 
is not valid C# syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is `IEnumerable<string> newList = item.Value;` instead of `object value = new { item.Key = item.Value };`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something with the dynamic keyword and the ExpandoObject (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-5.0), but if you're keys are so dynamic, I don't see a point of having them in a class/object at all. Rather store the data as a dictionary, which will then let you retreive data from strings as well.